# How can I add aceleration to this jQuery animation?

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, effect

I was able to animate my `<div>` ( [more info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7121147/slideup-only-hides-cant-show-using-slideup) ) from `bottom:-100px` to `bottom:0px`.

Now I'd like to have different speeds: Start a bit slower at the beginning of the animation and then get faster by the end of the animation.

This is how it looks:

```
$('#bannerFijo').animate({ bottom: '-15px' }, 1000, function() {
                    $('#bannerFijo').animate({ bottom: '0px' }, 100);
});
```

But I'm sure there must be another way so that the speed changes progressively.

-edit-

Animated version two:

```
$('#bannerFijo').animate({ bottom: '0px' }, 1200, function() {
                    $('#bannerFijo').animate({ bottom: '-15px' }, 300,function() {
                        $('#bannerFijo').animate({ bottom: '-5px' }, 150,function() {
                            $('#bannerFijo').animate({ bottom: '-10px' }, 100,function() {
                                $('#bannerFijo').animate({ bottom: '0px' }, 50);
                                    return true;
                                });
                            });
                    });
        });
```

-Edit- 
Thanks to SuperPaperSam i got to this solution ('no' plugins)

```
$.easing.easeOutBounce = function (x, t, b, c, d) {
            if ((t/=d) < (1/2.75)) {
                return c*(7.5625*t*t) + b;
            } else if (t < (2/2.75)) {
                return c*(7.5625*(t-=(1.5/2.75))*t + .75) + b;
            } else if (t < (2.5/2.75)) {
                return c*(7.5625*(t-=(2.25/2.75))*t + .9375) + b;
            } else {
                return c*(7.5625*(t-=(2.625/2.75))*t + .984375) + b;
            }

    }
```

So the animate function look like this:

```
function mostrar_banner(){

        $('#bannerFijo').animate({ bottom: '+=110px' }, 2000, 'easeOutBounce'); 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jquery allows for easing, check out the [easing plugin](http://gsgd.co.uk/sandbox/jquery/easing/).

It would look like this (un tested)

```
$('#bannerFijo').animate({ bottom: '-15px' }, 1000, nameofeasing, function() {
                $('#bannerFijo').animate({ bottom: '0px' }, 100, nameofeasing);
});
```

Edit: I Created a test page of this not using the easing plugin http://jsfiddle.net/EbJBn/2/

Comment: can't add any plugin :( only native Jquery functions.. (it's not my call)

Comment: I can see your edit, would it work without plugins? what nameofeasing you suggest? thanks!

Comment: easeInOutQuad is my favorite, you could define it like this http://api.jquery.com/animate/#easing in your document

Comment: $('#bannerFijo').animate({ bottom: '-15px' }, 1200,specialEasing: {  height: 'easeInOutQuad' }, function() {
     /**/
  }); 
Shall this work????

Comment: Do not apollogize, you have been very helpfull!!!! i will edit so you can see my current animate (it's kind of funny)

Answer (score 2):

You can use any animation "easing" function within jQuery without a plugin.  It's discussed in detail in this question I posted a few months ago...

[Looking for jQuery easing functions without using a plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5207301/looking-for-jquery-easing-functions-without-using-a-plugin)

The thread above contains the jQuery easing functions [in the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5207301/looking-for-jquery-easing-functions-without-using-a-plugin?answertab=active#tab-top) as well as [a link to more third party easing functions](http://www.robertpenner.com/easing/) (the 2nd and 3rd links on that page will download the functions).

Looking [at the demos here](http://jqueryui.com/demos/effect/easing.html), it seems like `easeInCirc` fits your description.

Manually add the specific easing function(s) to your `<script>`...

```
$.easing.easeInCirc = function (x, t, b, c, d) {
    return -c * (Math.sqrt(1 - (t/=d)*t) - 1) + b;
}
```

Then you would simply call it from your existing jQuery `animate()` functions by placing it just after the `duration` parameter.

```
$('#bannerFijo').animate({ bottom: '-15px' }, 1000, 'easeInCirc', function() {
                $('#bannerFijo').animate({ bottom: '0px' }, 100, 'easeInCirc');
});
```

**[Here is a JSFiddle with the `animate()` function slowed for illustration.](http://jsfiddle.net/KduwJ/5/)**

Answer (score 1):

you mean [easing?](http://gsgd.co.uk/sandbox/jquery/easing/)

Another Idea: why not bring the easing code to your javascript file?
Here's my take on it in [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PgMZB/)
You may select your desired easing and cut off others, if plugin size is bothering you.
Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion but i need only native Jquery functions; can't add any plugin :(

Comment: oh then you can use either swing or linear easing that comes pre built with the jquery.